# ml-kit - barcode-scanning android - Google code scanner

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I am using Google code scanner   Android MLKit for Barcode scanning. I am using below dependencies. I want the use bundled model so that initialisation time is not taken when app is launched. Is there a way can I use bundled version of model :

Please find below dependencies I used for this :

**implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-code-scanner:16.0.0'**

**AndroidManifest:**

When I used the above dependencies , I see below exception during downloading the model:
**Waiting for the Barcode UI module to be downloaded.**

Is there a way can I use bundled version of model so that I need not wait for Barcode UI module to be downloaded. Please help me regarding this

Thanks in Adavance.

Comment: Bundled version is not supported for code scanner feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  // Use this dependency to bundle the model with your app
  implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.1.0'
}
```

Found at: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android

Comment: I am using Google  play services code scanner. Can this dependency also be included along with Google play services code scanner dependency and remove the metadata from manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

According to this link: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/tips/installation-path Google play services code scanner is only available unbundled. (It is downloaded by google play services and seems to be a bit unreliable tbh)

If you want a bundled model it seems you have to use the full ML Kit version `'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.2.0'` as in SudoKoach's answer.